# I'm building a chrome extension and I need to pull information from another page. Would I do that with a background page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need a chrome extension to run a script only on website x, but pull information from the HTML elements of website Y. Is that possible? For example, if I wanted to display imdb movie ratings along with rotten tomatoes ratings every time someone navigated to rotten tomatoes, would that be possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, that's possible. First you need to [add permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) for the imdb site in manifest.json. Something like this:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://*.imdb.com/"
],
```

After adding the permission you can send ajax request to any of the imdb url from [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). In your case I think it's better to send the ajax request from content script. If you send the request from background page, you'll need to pass the pulled information to content script using [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

You can add something like this in manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": ["https://*.rottentomatoes.com/*"],
  "js": ["myscript.js"]
 }
],
```

and then you can send an ajax request to imdb urls from `myscript.js`.

**Just a suggestion:** Instead of pulling html pages from imdb site and then parsing the required info, it might be better to use an api. Something like http://www.omdbapi.com/.

Comment: @Vikas np. If you find the answer useful, plz accept the answer :)